# How can I stack two same-sized canvas on top of each other?

Tags: css, html

Below is le code. I want movementCanvas underneath canvas.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <canvas id="canvas" width="710" height="597" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
    <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas!</p>
  </canvas>

  <canvas id="movementCanvas" width="710" height="597" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
  </canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Second question. At a higher level, I'm trying to hide the canvas below. The movementCanvas is a color-coded map where I'll look up what value is there when clicked, and the only way to access the pixels is by using the HTML5 canvas and context. The top "canvas" is the front end and should look nice. Does that sound like a sane way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use CSS's `position: absolute`. Add the following CSS to your page:

```
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This will put both canvases at the same spot: the topleft-most part.

You might want to put them in a wrapper element, which will need to be `position: relative` in order for its child elements to be. For example, your HTML will look something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

And your CSS will look like this:

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.wrapper canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then position the wrapper div however you'd position the other stuff.

Comment: First question: what's the point of the wrapper div? Is it just to keep the two canvas together?

Second question: "canvas" is a 2D clickable map for a game. Because of positioning, my canvas clicks are no longer being detected. How can I deal with that?

Comment: The wrapper div exists for positioning. To be able to register clicks on BOTH canvases...not totally sure. Could you possibly consolidate them into 1 canvas?

Comment: If you really need two canvases, you could have the canvas that's on top send events to the canvas on bottom.

Comment: So for example, the clicked canvas would have an event handler that does the work I want on the other canvas? Is that what you mean?

Comment: The reason for the second, hidden canvas is to quickly look up the color-coded information that isn't on the first, "front end" canvas. Is there a way that I can just hide the second canvas? The problem is that I need to be able to call context.getImageData() so I can look up pixels at (x,y). I'm unsure whether the getImageData() call will work if this second canvas is hidden or 1x1. Any thoughts?

Comment: To your first comment, yes: the clicked canvas would trigger identical events on the other canvas. Not sure, but could you use visibility: hidden and hide the 2nd canvas?

Comment: Handling clicks for both canvas works for me and I think I'm on my way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For further readers, why not listening to the wrapper ? After all you just need position and click information...

Comment: Worked fine, but the wrapper div would have size 0x0 so other parts of the page would be layed-out on top. To solve that I let the first canvas use posistion: static

Comment: I think the comment of @David Lilljegren is very relevant, especially for beginners like me. I really didn't understand why my div's changed shape after applying your solution. Giving the first canvas a static position and all other canvases an absolute position (with top and left at 0) solved this. Maybe a small PS at the bottom of the answer could save future readers a lot of time.

Comment: Old topic but I wonder: this would be useful (in several instances for me) if the wrapper could guess its size from the size of its content. Does CSS/JS allow for that?