# Canvas - bezier repeat

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm a french programmer, so excuse my English :

I make a canvas with a wave and i can't find where i must clear my canvas for good visual effect, it's my code :

```
window.onload = function()
{
    var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');









if (canvas.getContext)

        // If you have it, create a canvas user inteface element.
        {


          // Paint it black.
          context.fillStyle = "black";
          context.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000); 
          context.fill();

          // Paint the starfield.


          vague();
          stars();
          decor();
         }

function stars() {

        // Draw 50 stars.
        for (i = 0; i <= 70; i++) {
          // Get random positions for stars.
          var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800)
          var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)

          // Make the stars white
          context.fillStyle = "white";
          context.shadowColor = 'white';
          context.shadowBlur = 50;

          // Give the ship some room.
          if (x < 0 || y < 0) context.fillStyle = "black";

          // Draw an individual star.
          context.beginPath();
          context.arc(x, y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
          context.closePath();
          context.fill();

        }
      }

function decor() {



                context.beginPath();
                context.shadowColor = 'white';
        context.shadowBlur = 30;
        context.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
        context.fillRect(0,400,1000,200);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill(); 


        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = 'white';
        context.shadowColor = 'white';
        context.shadowBlur = 1500;
        context.shadowOffsetX = -300;
        context.shadowOffsetY = 400;
        context.arc(680,110,100,Math.PI*2,false);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill(); 

}


function vague (){

    draw(-120,50);
    var i = 0;

    function draw(x,y){



          for ( var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {


            var x = x+50;
            var y = y;



            context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,100,0.4)';
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(72+x, 356+y);   // Tracer autre une ligne (théorique)
            context.strokeStyle = 'skyblue';
            context.lineWidth=3;
            context.bezierCurveTo(60+x, 360+y , 92+x , 332+y , 104+x , 323+y );
            context.bezierCurveTo(114+x, 316+y , 128+x , 304+y , 140+x , 325+y );
            context.bezierCurveTo(148+x, 339+y  , 127+x, 307+y , 115+x , 337+y );
            context.bezierCurveTo(109+x, 352+y , 159+x , 357+y , 144+x , 357+y );
            context.bezierCurveTo(129+x, 357+y , 87+x , 356+y , 72+x , 356+y );
            context.fill();
            context.stroke(); 


                if (x>=800){
                   x=-120;

                }

          }

        setInterval( function () { draw(x,y) }, 50);
        x = x+20;



  }

}
};
```

Thanks for your answer i can't find my mistake, i become CRAZY !

Comment: Could you please put up a jsFiddle and explain a little more what you want the effect to be?

Comment: sorry, i put up that now, the wave don't want to clear, it repeat good but all there superpose and i don't know where i must clearrect for don't have superposition

Comment: Could you please put it on jsFiddle or JS Bin, so I can actually see it working? ( http://jsfiddle.net/ )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Znmhq/ i don't know if it's good i have never work with jsfiddle

Comment: I don't see anything displaying - is that your issue in the first place?

Comment: yes i don't know they don't run on the website it's all my code !! i have just put out link javascript css and html meta

Comment: Hm. I would like to move this to chat, but you don't have high enough rep. Give me a second to try some things out.

Comment: i can't send you zip ??

Comment: I posted an answer based on running it separately myself.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to put your waves on a different canvas with a transparent background that is on top of your background canvas. Then you just clear the canvas (or the area where the waves are rendered) at the start of each `draw` call. That way, you don't need to rerender whatever background as well.

In order to do that, you would [use CSS to place the canvases on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10037727/2280630). You would also just give the other canvas a different id, like `<canvas id="vagueCanvas"></canvas>` and select the context the same way `var vagueContext = document.getElementById( 'vagueCanvas' ).getContext( '2d' );`.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand where i place my new canvas ?? and how i call him on JS file ?

Comment: I added the steps in the answer.

Comment: okay i do that !  how i can define a transparent background ?

Comment: The canvas background is already transparent. You just don't render a background onto it like you did with the first one (don't do this step `context.fillStyle = "black"; context.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000); context.fill();`).

Comment: okay thx a lot for all of your answer i need to know where i clear my canvas now ?

Comment: Just add `context.clearRect( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 )` to the top of your `draw` function. And please consider accepting the answer.