# Placing two canvas elements on top of each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, canvas

I know this has been asked a few times already on SO (e.g.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037649/how-can-i-stack-two-same-sized-canvas-on-top-of-each-other)), but I don't seem to be able to get this to work.

I'm trying to:

1. display images
2. place a canvas on top of each of them
3. get a user to draw on the top canvas based on the image underneath
4. get the data off all canvases to be stored locally.

I haven't been able to get the CSS to work so that the canvases are on top of each other and I've tried several ways of doing it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="pb-2 justify-content-center">
    <h2><strong>Drawing test</strong></h2>
    <div class="justify-content-center">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
            <div class="wrapper">
                <canvas id="dorsal" height="512" width="512"></canvas>
                <canvas id="dorsal-duplicate" height="512" width="512"></canvas>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
canvas {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.wrapper {
position: relative;
width: 512px;
height: 512px;
}

.wrapper canvas {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("dorsal"), ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("dorsal-duplicate"), ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

var background1 = new Image();
var to_draw_on = new Image();

background1.src = "{% static aspects.Dorsal.0 %}";  /* image from Django static folder */

background1.onload = function(){ctx1.drawImage(background1,0,0);}
to_draw_on.onload = function(){ctx2.drawImage(to_draw_on,0,0);}

/* code to draw on the second canvas */
```

This only results in the second canvas being beneath the first canvas, so that when I go to draw, I won't be able to trace the outline of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am not sure why your version does not work (it should as-is!), but here's a version that uses your code and a bit of CSS to check the overlap. Read the comments in the CSS. When done, remove the extra code and enable `.wrapper canvas { top: 0 }` again.

Without the Javascript, I might add, I don't use Django.

However, it seems your JS `new Image()` has no size parameters and `ctx.drawimage` only has a location (0,0) but no (height,width) to work with.

So, height=0, width=0 yields nothing to overlap...

Forgot to mention: give both `canvas` a `z-index` so you can control which is on top.

**UPDATE**

Added Javascript and a third `canvas` to prove the code works as expected. Also inserted `z-index` per canvas as suggested before. Retrieving a few random pics from 'Lorem Picsum' to fill the canvas.

NOTICE that I use proper width/height parameters in my Javascript....

```js
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("dorsal")          , ctx1 = canvas1.getContext("2d");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("dorsal-duplicate"), ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var canvas3 = document.getElementById("extra-img")       , ctx3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");

var background1 = new Image(512,256);
var to_draw_on  = new Image(512,256);
var extra_img   = new Image(512,256);

background1.src = "https://picsum.photos/512/512?random=0";
to_draw_on.src  = "https://picsum.photos/512/512?random=1";
extra_img.src   = "https://picsum.photos/512/512?random=2";

background1.onload = function(){ctx1.drawImage(background1,0,0);}
to_draw_on.onload  = function(){ctx2.drawImage(to_draw_on,0,0);}
extra_img.onload   = function(){ctx3.drawImage(extra_img,0,0);}

/* code to draw on the second canvas */
```

```css
.wrapper {
position: relative;
width : 512px;
height: 512px;
}

.wrapper canvas {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
/* top : 0; /* temporary disabled */

/*ADDED*/
width: 100%; height: 100%; /* fill-parent */
border: 2px dotted black;
}

/*
    To check the overlap:
    - make #dorsal fill the top half of 512px
    - make #dorsal-duplicate fill the bottom half of 512px
*/
#dorsal {
    top : 0;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 1;
}
#dorsal-duplicate {
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50%;

    z-index: 2;
}
#extra-img {
    background-color: blue;
    left: 64px; bottom: 128px;
    height: 50%; width: 75%;

    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pb-2 justify-content-center">
        <h2>
            <strong>Drawing test</strong>
        </h2>
        <p>removed width/height values from &lt;canvas&gt;, redundant.
        <div class="justify-content-center">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <canvas id="dorsal"          ></canvas>
                    <canvas id="dorsal-duplicate"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="extra-img"       ></canvas>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. When I removed the inline styling from the canvases, they both just shrunk to 300*150 pixel boxes and are just sitting next to each other. If it's any help, I'm using Bootstrap 4 for CSS and I'm loading this into a Django template. Maybe Bootstrap 4 is the culprit?

Comment: First things first: does the code I gave run on Stackoverflow in your browser? You should see a 512x512px square, upper half green, lower half red. It does on W10 Firefox (mine). Furthermore, on SO we have to work with what we're given. If it still doesn't work, without full/more code it's anybody's guess. Could be bootstrap, could be some injected code from apps you run in the browsers' background...

Comment: Test again by putting parameters in like `new Image(512,512)` and in `ctx.drawimage`

Comment: Hmm. I haven't done what you just suggested, but I tried using JS to force the position as absolute and that seems to have pushed them on top of each other - I assume that if I use inline styling or JS I can get this thing to work. I'm still confused why CSS doesn't do it?

Comment: Check the update, this is all I can do for you right now given the code you posted.

Comment: I'll accept yours as the right answer, because I believe it works. However, I can't exactly say why it still doesn't work on my development environment.

Comment: Thanks for the accept! My advice: start a new document and use my code as a starting point. You now know at least that part works as expected. Maybe create something without Django/Bootstrap first to get the hang of canvas manipulation first, without having to worry about making mistakes using some framework syntax.

Comment: I'm such an ass. I forgot that when updating CSS in Django during development it's not enough to just refresh the page to get the updated CSS. Your code definitely works ‍♂️

Comment: LOL, well, now that you have pulled your head from between your butt cheeks, you will notice that the world looks much brighter! Okay, [Ctrl-F5] might have worked too. One mistake you'll never make again, I guess...

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

usage of static template tag is

```
{% static 'static_file_here.extension' %}
```

so basically the code `background1.src = "{% static aspects.Dorsal.0 %}";`
should be `background1.src = "{% static 'aspects.Dorsal.0' %}";`

Comment: I've loaded the file locations of these images into the Django database and I'm pulling them from there and thus, what I've written works and what you have put doesn't. Doing it my way let's me connect each image with a classification done on a previous view and in this view I'm displaying those same images so that the user can trace on top of the images. Anyway, that's not the issue. The issues is that I can't get the canvases to be on top of each other.